# DataGridView WinForms Auto Reload/Update/Refresh

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form with a `DataGridView` control.

I bound it into an attached DB file (.mdf).

I perform insertion by generating a dynamic Insert statement. I then pump this sql statement into a `SqlCommand` object and perform `ExecuteNonQuery()` method. All of these is performed by handling a `Button` click event. The button and the gridview is located on the same form.

```
Public Sub InsertRow(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal param3 As String)

    Dim strConn As String = (the connection string)
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)

    Dim insertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO theTable VALUES ('" + param1 + "', '" + param2 + "', '" + param3 + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "')"
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(insertSQL, sqlConn)
    sqlConn.Open()
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click

    InsertRow("a","b","c")

End Sub
```

After the code execution, the `DataGridView` is not updating (remains intact). I have to exit the form and reload it to have the updated gridview.

For certain reasons, I can't use `DataTable` object.
But I would like to have this gridview updated everytime I run the insertion.

Can someone tell me how to do it?
Thank's

P.S Although I am doing this in VB, I don't mind receiving answer in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to use `SQLCommand` and `Parameters` to avoid sql injection since you are using `SQLClient` namespace. Try this as your `Insert` procedure.

```
Private Sub InsertSQL(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal param3 As String)

    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere")
        Using sqlComm As New SqlCommand()
            sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sqlComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO theTable VALUES (@Param1,@Param2,@Param3,@Param4,@Param5)"
            With sqlComm.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@Param1", param1)
                .AddWithValue("@Param2", param2)
                .AddWithValue("@Param3", param3)
                .AddWithValue("@Param4", Now)
                .AddWithValue("@Param5", Now)
            End With

            Try
                sqlConn.Open()
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error No. " & ex.ErrorCode.ToString)
            Finally
                sqlConn.Close()
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Secondly, why don't you prefer to use `DataTable` to bind your `DataGridView`? Well, here's another solution. It's ny using `SQLDataReader` and you have to loop on it to put the records in your grid.

```
Private Sub ReloadGrid(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Dim queryString As String = "Your Query Here"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() ' Clear All Rows '

        While reader.Read()
           ' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",  reader(0), reader(1))) '
           ' Insert the record in your datagrid '
           Dim row As String() = New String() {reader(0).ToString, reader(1).ToString, reader(2).ToString}
           DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        End While

        ' Call Close when done reading. '
        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Haha.. Nope.. It's John who decided to voluntarily write a ready made code.. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ADO.net use `.EndEdit()` / `.Validate()` method

Comment: I am using SqlConnection & SqlCommand, there are no such methods there.

Comment: are you doing the bindings programmatically? how are you binding it and where do you call you function that binds

Comment: Nope, not programatically. I simply set everything using the built in Visual Studio feature. I just simply choose the data source by doing few clicks.

Comment: then you need to bind to that datasource programmatically after your update.. it seems your control is not maintaining a connection to database thats why its not updating your grid. so you have to bind it again

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a procedure or function to be responsible for reloading data, you can use to make a new call to the methods that you use to load data to datagrid.

```
Public Sub InsertRow(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal param3 As String)

    Dim strConn As String = (the connection string)
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)

    Dim insertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO theTable VALUES ('" + param1 + "', '" + param2 + "', '" + param3 + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "')"
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(insertSQL, sqlConn)
    sqlConn.Open()
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConn.Close()
    ReLoadData(grid)
End Sub

Private Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click

    InsertRow("a","b","c")

End Sub

Private Sub ReloadData(ByVAl sender as DataGridView)
 ' Implement your data load function
 ' I use for example
  sender.datasource = GetTable() 'GetTable is a function that return a DataTable Object With my data 
  sender.DataSource = Nothing    'Free the DataGridView DataSource property for enable row edition.

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't prefer using `DataTable`. I am actually trying to find another way to do this. I have mentioned this in my question.

Comment: as soon as you set `sender.DataSource = Nothing`, gridview would be empty I suppose, if I am not wrong..

Comment: ya.. why u set datasource into nothing right after binding it into a datatable?

Answer (score 0):

you can programmatically set the `dataSource` to `null` and again set the actual `dataSource` to reload the gridview..

but the control will hang for some few secs..(even suspendLayout may not work)

other than this I don't know how to refresh.. even if you refresh, update etc it will not update the once bound datagrid control

Comment: I am actually considering doing this. But for certain reason, I can't pump data from data souce into any data set.

Comment: @deletedaccount: is it a performance reason or some other reason?

Comment: is this a huge table(lots or rows and possibly many large columns)?

is this table accessed/updated by many?

if so, you may want to change GUI to allow user select a subset to display/edit the table