# Implement Background Worker Class in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, linq-to-sql

I am working on an application which is guest house management system.it works fine but what i want is to embed the background worker class in my project.

here is how it looks
[image]

I want list of rooms to be updated automatically on saving the information on the Add room form.For displaying room i am using grid-view and for adding new room i created a new form and add LINQ to SQL query code to save the information of new room.

How should i go about it in C#. Any alternate suggestion would also be appreciated.

Comment: What your room collection is? If it's an observable collection for the gridview then it would be updated automatically. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306809/datagridview-winforms-auto-reload-update-refresh too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new thread that is separated in your current thread.

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(delegate()
{
// Perform your task here
});
```

and when you want to call it, just invoke the

```
workerThread.Start();
```